# Planet API KeyError:location problem with get_assets_by_id()

Tags: python, api, planet

I'm trying to download a list of planet scenes with get_assets_by_id. Scenes were selected visially through Planet Explorer and theirs IDs  were copied.  But I keep recieving messege **KeyError: 'location'** after the first image in the list have benn dowloaded.

Here is my code:

```
for ids in id_list:
    my_asset = client.get_assets_by_id('PSScene4Band', ids).get()
    client.activate(my_asset['analytic'])
    my_asset = client.get_assets_by_id('PSScene4Band', ids).get()
    callback = api.write_to_file('**dir**')
    body = client.download(my_asset['analytic'], callback=callback)
    body.await()
    time.sleep(30)
```

So, what is the reason for this error?

Comment: I've figured it out. Probably, the problem was that Planet explorer site was open in browser under the same account.

Comment: This example with checking response code helped me a lot
[link](https://gist.github.com/quintenvanmoerbeke/7a219ee667e915ddb53f074861c604a4)